# Deploy en Heroku - Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, heroku

Tengo un WebServer hecho en nodejs/express, todo perfecto... Al intentar hacer el Deploy en Heroku (Que segun se hace exitosamente) e intentar abrir mi Web Aparece lo siguiente

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
>   You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

No tengo idea alguna de cual sea el problema, ¿alguien que me pueda asistir? Si es necesario, puedo compartir el codigo de otros archivos.

index.js

```
// Requires
const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
const hbs = require('hbs');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Import Helpers
require('./helpers/helper');

// Middlewares
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// HBS Template Engine
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials'); // Directorio de los partials
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');  // Definimos el engine a usar

// Routes
app.use(require('./routes/routes'));    // Cargamos el archivo con todas las rutas

app.listen(port, () => {    // Abrimos el puerto
    console.log(`Running in port ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: Intenta usando el port 5000, ya que `process.env.PORT` no esta definido, usa las `config vars` que se pueden usar con `process.env`

Comment: Recuerda usar siempre mayúsculas al definir una `config var`

Comment: Añadí una respuesta, tuve que corregirla por tuve errores de escritura xd lo siento

Comment: Deberías subir el `log` de tu aplicación para ver donde se produce el fallo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un ligero error al definir el template para express, tu código debería verse así:

```
// Requires
const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
const hbs = require('hbs');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Import Helpers
require('./helpers/helper');

// Middlewares
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// HBS Template Engine
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials'); // Directorio de los partials
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');  // Definimos el engine a usar
app.engine('hbs', hbs.__express);
// Routes
app.use(require('./routes/routes'));    // Cargamos el archivo con todas las rutas

app.listen(port, () => {    // Abrimos el puerto
    console.log(`Running in port ${port}`)
});
```

Te falto añadir `app.engine('hbs', hbs.__express)`

Obviamente crearías archivos con la extensión `.hbs` para que express use ese archivo como template

Editado: Error de escritura xd

Comment: Hola @Rimuru, gracias por responder. Segun entiendo, `app.set('view engine', 'hbs);` me permite indicarle a Express que se usara un Template Engine, y por lo caul debera leer los archivos hbs. Corregi el error (aunque no se como) Gracias a un repositorio que tengo con el mismo proyecto a hacer, que hasta donde veo, es exactamente igual que el que estaba haciendo desde 0. Aun sin la linea de codigo que indicas, funciona

Comment: @http.keegan Te dejo un ejemplo aquí https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started